# How to implement this C++ source in python?

Tags: c++, python

This is the code:

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
    for(int j=1; j<=10; ++j)
        cin >> G[i][j];
```

This is a two dimension array G, and I want to store the data from G[1][1], not from zero.

How to implement this code in python?

Comment: `cin >>` is C++ not C. Array of what: characters? integers? strings?

Comment: I'd do something like `[[int(raw_input()) for _ in range(0, 11)] for _ in range (0, 11)]` but I don't really get the 'index from 1' part

Comment: Not sure why you would need to do something like this...

Comment: Why would you "want to store the data from `G[1][1]`", when the array will start at 0 no matter what you "want", and `[10]` will not be a valid index unless the array size is at least `[11]`? C++ doesn't care about what you want; it cares only about what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import random
>>> G = [[0]*11 for _ in range(11)]
>>> G
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> for i in range(1, 11):
        for j in range(1, 11):
            G[i][j] = random.randint(1,10)


>>> G
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 7, 8, 10, 5, 7, 9, 8, 10, 8, 3], [0, 7, 9, 7, 7, 6, 6, 10, 2, 8, 9], [0, 10, 6, 3, 7, 10, 7, 9, 6, 1, 7], [0, 5, 7, 1, 10, 3, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6], [0, 7, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 10, 10, 8, 1], [0, 10, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1], [0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 2, 3, 8, 1, 6, 4], [0, 7, 8, 5, 8, 1, 9, 5, 5, 2, 9], [0, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 7, 7, 5, 5], [0, 3, 4, 10, 1, 2, 5, 3, 10, 9, 7]]
```

`random.randint` was used in place of `input()` or `raw_input()` to show that this works.

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in xrange(1, 11):
    for j in xrange(1, 11):
        G[i][j] = raw_input()
```

<strike>or a more pythonic way, assuming G is empty before your loops:</strike>

```
G = [[raw_input() for j in xrange(1, 11)] for i in xrange(1, 11)]
```

(doesn't work, those lists would have the first value at element 0 which is not what the OP wants)

Comment: what's G's type? if it's a list or tuple, it's still 0-based, which may not be what he wants.

Comment: also remove that ugly semicolon!

Comment: @ott--: The end value is exclusive. `range(1, 11) ==  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

Comment: the first one is more readable than the second one. Or maybe I'm not used to pythonic ways...

Answer (score 2):

Initialising `G`:

```
G = [[0 for i in xrange(11)] for i in xrange(11)]
```

<s>or `G = [[0]*11]*11`</s>

Populating `G`:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    for j in xrange(10):
        G[i+1][j+1] = int(raw_input())
```

If you want to construct `G` in-place, you could do it with a nested list comprehension similar to the initialisation

Comment: @PreetKukreti, try: `>>> G = [[0]*5]*5
>>> G[0][0]=2
>>> G`

Comment: `G = [[0]*11]*11` is the wrong way to initialize G. The same object is shared between `G[i][0]`. When you modify `G[0][0]`, it'll also modify all `G[i][0]` value.

Comment: @warwaruk yep you are right thanks, 11 references to the same list. Not sure how I missed that

Comment: @PreetKukreti, this is classical :)

Comment: I thought the same thing so i did mine correctly then when i saw @Preet's code i thought that was quicker but forgot to test it...

Comment: You can still do `G = [[0]*11 for _ in range(11)]`, you dont need a range for the first time because 0 is immutable.

Comment: @jamylak why "G = [[0]*11]*11" this way the G[i][0](0<=i<10) will be the same?

Comment: @Dikei why "G = [[0]*11]*11" this way the G[i][0](0<=i<10) will be the same?

Comment: Yeah i know but I'm saying you can still do `G = [[0]*11 for _ in range(11)]` because the 0 is immutable so it doesn't copy by reference in that case. However, as you said, you can't do `G = [[0]*11]*11`

Answer (score 1):

Using dictionaries:

```
G = {}
for i in xrange(1, 11):
    G[i] = {}
    for j in xrange(1, 11):
        G[i][j] = raw_input()
```

Using lists (but starting indexes from 0):

```
G = []
for _ in xrange(1, 11):
    row = []
    G.append(row)
    for _ in xrange(1, 11):
        row.append(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 1):

If readability counts, this is also quite readable

```
G=[[0]*11 for _ in range(11)]
for (i,j) in itertools.product(range(1,11),range(1,11)):
    while True:
        try: 
            G[i][j]=int(raw_input())
            break
         except ValueError:
            None
```