# The initialization of 2-dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, initialization

I asked a question about initializing a 2 dimensional array yesterday, this is the link:
[How to implement this C++ source in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137652/how-to-implement-this-c-source-in-python)

There is a problem in the answer, a friend mentioned a way:

```
G = [[0]*11]*11
```

But in this way, when I change the `G[0][0]` to `2`, all the `G[i][0](0<=i<11)` will all change to `2`, but I don't know why?

**Supplement:**

This is what I thought:
The `0` or other number is `immutable`, so we change one of them, the others will not be changed.
But the list [0, 0 ,0 ,.....] is `mutable`, so when we [0, 0, ...] * 11, all the [0, 0, ...] list will be the same, as `is` function is True. am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have 11 references to the same list.

```
G = [[0] * 11 for x in range(11)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `*11` notation makes 11 references to the same object. If the object is immutable you don't notice, because any attempt to change it changes the reference to a different object. When the object is mutable you can modify it, like assigning to a member of a list; since all the references are to the same object, all of them get modified at the same time.

Mutable/immutable might seem to change things, but it doesn't - Python is being consistent in both cases. Consider this example:

```
G[0] = [3]*11
```

You'll see that G[1] has not changed.

Comment: sorry, I don't know"Mutable/immutable might seem to change things, but it doesn't - Python is being consistent in both cases" this means? why"since all the references are to the same object, all of them get modified at the same time"